# String expression in integer result

Tags: php, regex

After a lot of operations I've got some like:

```
$exr = "2+3/1.5";
```

How I can get result of this expression? Like this:

```
$result = (floatval)$exr; // show: 4
```

Of course it doesn't work. I've got only 2, first symbol.
Any easy way to solve this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use the PHP [`eval`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.eval.php) function like this:

```
$exr = '2+3/1.5';
eval('$result = ' . $exr . ';');
var_dump($result);
// float(4)
```

**Read this note carefully**:

> Caution: The eval() language construct is very dangerous because it allows
>   execution of arbitrary PHP code. Its use thus is discouraged. If you
>   have carefully verified that there is no other option than to use this
>   construct, pay special attention not to pass any user provided data
>   into it without properly validating it beforehand.

Comment: Here any way for make regex which only work with math functions and operations? Like: +; -; /; *; sqrt; pow; cos; sin; etc?

Comment: How come you are discouraging the use of eval and giving the same solution?

Answer (score 2):

## [Eval is EVIL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/951373/when-is-eval-evil-in-php)

I dont know why every answer here is telling you to do this? But avoid using this.

Here is very good function that can do the same **without the eval()** <sup>*[Source](http://www.website55.com/php-mysql/2010/04/how-to-calculate-strings-with-php.html)*</sup>

```
function calculate_string( $mathString )    {
    $mathString = trim($mathString);     // trim white spaces
    $mathString = ereg_replace ('[^0-9\+-\*\/\(\) ]', '', $mathString);    // remove any non-numbers chars; exception for math operators
 
    $compute = create_function("", "return (" . $mathString . ");" );
    return 0 + $compute();
}
```

Use it as

```
$exr = '2+3/1.5';
echo calculate_string($exr);
```

Comment: Good idea! But need to correct regex a little bit. Cause in math available also cos, sin, pow, etc.

Answer (score 1):

You could use the [eval](http://php.net/manual/en/function.eval.php) function:

```
$result = eval($exr); // show: 4
```

Comment: Thanks a lot. I can't understand how "googling" with that question?! Bad English :)

Comment: You could try [this query](https://www.google.com/search?q=calculate+math+operation+in+PHP) or see Salman comment's on the accepted answer :)

Answer (score 1):

Try:

```
$exr = "2+3/1.5";
echo eval("return $exr;"); //shows 4
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use eval.

```
$result = eval($exr);
```

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way would be to just run it through eval(), but that is very insecure. For security I'd recommend to filter certain characters, like a-z and special chars like ";:'.